# How to match/merge data from two different files in R?

Tags: r, merge, match

I have two files (file1.csv and file2.csv). As shown below, file1 contains two columns date and variable x1 that has 365 observations (whole year). file 2 contains column date as file1 and many other variables. I'm interested only in variable x45 that has 24 observations only (2 observations each month).

file1

```
date     x1
1/01/2005   33
2/01/2005   24
3/01/2005    72
31/12/2005   52
```

file 2

```
date     x2      x3     x45
1/01/2005               115
5/02/2005                125
13/04/2005               127
31/12/2005               138
```

so I'd like to add column x45 to file1.csv to look like

```
date    x1    x45
1/01/2005   33  115
2/01/2005   24    NA
3/01/2005    72   NA
31/12/2005   52           138
```

I have tried using

```
file1= read.csv("D:/file1.csv")
file2= read.csv("D:/file2.csv")
file3 = merge(file1, file2)
```

However, file 3 has only 24 rows (observations) and omits the rest of observations in file 1.

Any help to get the result as described above would be much appreciated.

Comment: @RichardScriven    No they aren't. I just ignored writing their values as I don't need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2[c('date', 'x45')], by='date')
#         date x1 x45
#1  1/01/2005 33 115
#2  2/01/2005 24  NA
#3  3/01/2005 72  NA
#4 31/12/2005 52 138
```

Or using `merge`

```
merge(df1, df2[c('date', 'x45')], all.x=TRUE)
#       date x1 x45
#1  1/01/2005 33 115
#2  2/01/2005 24  NA
#3  3/01/2005 72  NA
#4 31/12/2005 52 138
```

#### Update

The `left_join` from `dplyr` and `join` from `plyr` keep the original order.  If you need to keep order in `merge`, one option is to create an "indx" in "df1" and after the `merge`, the original order can be retained using the "indx"

```
df1$indx <- 1:nrow(df1)
 merge(df1, df2[c('date', 'x45')], all.x=TRUE)[order(df1$indx),-3]
    date x1 x45
 #1  1/01/2005 33 115
 #2  2/01/2005 24  NA
 #3  3/01/2005 72  NA
 #4 31/12/2005 52 138
```

Or using `join` from `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
join(df1, df2[c('date', 'x45')], by='date', type='left')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("1/01/2005", "2/01/2005", "3/01/2005", 
"31/12/2005"), x1 = c(33L, 24L, 72L, 52L)), .Names = c("date", 
"x1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(date = c("1/01/2005", "5/02/2005", "13/04/2005", 
"31/12/2005"), x2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), x3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), 
x45 = c(115L, 125L, 127L, 138L)), .Names = c("date", "x2", 
 "x3", "x45"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: left_join didn't work with me. However, merge did work. Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @aelwan Not sure why it didn't work.  What is the error message?

Comment: there was no error message but all the values of x45 were NA.

Comment: what if I have different x45 columns in different files?

Comment: @Akurn your code changes the order of the rows. Any idea to avoid that?

Comment: @aelwant That is strange about getting the NA in `x45`.  It didn't happen with your example data.  What do you mean by 'different x45 columns'?   `left_join` won't change the order of rows, or even `join` from plyr wouldn't change order.  If you need to keep the original order in merge, I will update.  BTW, the example data didn't change the order

Comment: @Akurn. I can't thank you enough for your help. I meant by different x45 columns, like I have the same variable for  different locations and every location has a file. So it would be like file2_x45, file3_x45, file4_x45 and so on

Comment: @aelwan I am not sure I understand it clearly.  Are these `file2_x45`, `file3_x45` columns in `df2`?  Can you update your post with an example that reflect the change and the expected result?  It would be easier in that way to have some reference.

Comment: No. I meant other files like df3 and df4 and so on not df2. However, I managed to do it. Thank you so much

Comment: @aelwan. You have to put all the files in a list and then do the `merge`.  I would have use `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='date'), list(df1, df2, df3))`, but not tested

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, you can join and update `file1` both very fast and by reference (without using `<-`) using the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(file1), date)[file2, x45 := i.x45]
file1
#          date x1 x45
# 1:  1/01/2005 33 115
# 2:  2/01/2005 24  NA
# 3:  3/01/2005 72  NA
# 4: 31/12/2005 52 138
```

Here you key `file1` by the `date` column and perform a binary join on `file2` while pulling only the `x45` column

Answer (score 0):

The following will also work, without requiring a package, and without changing the original order of the rows in df1:

```
df1
#        date x1
#2  1/01/2005 33
#3  2/01/2005 24
#4  3/01/2005 72
#5 31/12/2005 52
df2
#        date x45
#1  1/01/2005  33
#2  2/01/2005  24
#3  3/01/2005  72
#4 31/12/2005  52

df1$x45 <- df2$x45[match(df1$date, df2$date)]

df1
#        date x1 x45
#2  1/01/2005 33  33
#3  2/01/2005 24  24
#4  3/01/2005 72  72
#5 31/12/2005 52  52
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I got NA in all x45 column